# Show columns of referenced table instead of the object in django admin

Tags: django, django-models

How can I show the columns *id*, *title* and the *year* of the book instead of "*Books object*"?

This screenshot shows the current state:

[image]

My model.py looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'authors'


class AuthorsBooks(models.Model):
    author_id = models.OneToOneField('Authors', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='author_id', primary_key=True)
    book_id = models.OneToOneField('Books', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='book_id', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'authors_books'
        unique_together = (('author_id', 'book_id'),)


class Awards(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField('Authors', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='author', primary_key=True)
    award_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'awards'
        unique_together = (('author', 'award_name'),)


class Books(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'books'
```

In the class AuthorsBooks I have changed the two foreign keys to OneToOneFields.

My admin.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Authors
...

class AwardsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Awards

class AuthorsBooksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AuthorsBooks

class AuthorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "birthday" )
    inlines = (AwardsInline, AuthorsBooksInline)


admin.site.register(Authors, AuthorsAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

In your models.py file, you can use the special `__str__`  method in your concerned class to make your objects more descriptive. (This is generally the way most programmers do it)

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.title #if your using 'title' as the attribute to identify your objects
```

You can choose any other attribute to make your object descriptive.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this is the more common way using "__str__", instead of using __unicode__, but probably both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a unicode function in your models.py per model.

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'authors'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thank  you it helped me a little bit, I've added    `def __unicode__(self): return self.title` to the `class Books(models.Model)`and now the title in the <select> was shown. But how can I change the <select> to a normal field and add the column _year_ ?

Comment: simply add year to the return of the unicode function, like this:
` return '{} - {}'.format(self.title, self.year)`. I now realize that I didn't answer your question. I'm sorry. Unfortunately I don't know how to render the columns that you want.

Comment: Thanks anyway, perhaps someone else has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode didnt work for me, but overriding **str** worked