# Using Foreign Key on Django model to populate select input

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, models

im having problems finding out on the documentation how to solve my problem so im posting here: 
I have 3 Models one for a class room with its attributes, one for students and the last one a relation of the room and the student.
So on the template i want it to show a select button with a option value being the student id and the label being the student name

on my models.py i have this:

```
student_id = models.ForeignKey('Student', verbose_name=u"Student")
```

on my template.html i just call the field:

```
  {{ field }}
```

and the result that i get is:

```
<select name='student_id'>
  <option value='1'>Student object</option>
</select>
```

is there a way that i can preset the value and label like its done using choices for static data? to something like this:

```
STUDENT_CHOICES =(
    (model.student.id , model.student.name),
)
student_id = models.ForeignKey('Student', verbose_name=u"Student",, choices=STUDENT_CHOICES)
```

let me know if im not clear enough on the question since im fairly new to python and django

Comment: i found the answer to my problem here, he explained the situation way better than me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663229/show-columns-of-referenced-table-instead-of-the-object-in-django-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out all i had to do was to set the default value to be returned by adding a unicode function to each model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.student_name
```

And the full model code below:

```
Class StudentRoom(models.Model):
    student_id  = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    room_id  = models.ForeignKey('Room')

Class Student(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.student_name

Class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    room_faction = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.room_name
```